# Patch circle by a color gradient

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm attempting to plot a color gradient which I would like to be uniform along an axis  (in the case of the picture below defined by the angle `pi/7`)

When I use the `patch` command, The plot matches the desired gradient direction, but is not uniform along it (all sorts of triangles are formed between the points along the circle)

[image]

here is the code

```
N=120;
theta = linspace(-pi,pi,N+1);
theta = theta(1:end-1);
c = exp(-6*cos(theta-pi/7));
figure(1)
patch(cos(theta),sin(theta),c)
ylabel('y'); xlabel('x')
axis equal
```

Comment: What is the question? Please be specific. See [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the `Faces`property to make sure the colours fill stripes perpendicular to the axis (see [Specifying Faces and Vertices](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bur8xd4-1)) . Otherwise, MATLAB will use some algorithm to blend the colour as smoothly as it sees.

```
N=120;
a = pi/7;

theta = linspace(a,2*pi+a,N+1); % note that I changed the point sequence, this is just to make it easier to produce the matrix for Faces.
theta(end) = [];

ids = (1:N/2)';
faces = [ids, ids+1, N-ids, N-ids+1];

c = exp(-6*cos(a-theta))';

figure
patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices',[cos(theta);sin(theta)]','FaceVertexCData',c, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
ylabel('y'); xlabel('x')
axis equal
```

[image]